# Crystal Reports Filtering and Organizing data

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a small Crystal Report using 2 tables (TICKET,HISTORY,CUSTOMER) from a database I was given access to.  I do not have access to modify the database tables to correct the issue and I am looking to see if this is possible.

The TICKET table is my main table and has a 1 to Many relation to HISTORY table.
The CUSTOMER table has 1 to Many relation to the TICKET table.

Inside the HISTORY table, there is column called Version.  Every time a HISTORY entry is added on a TICKET, the Version number is written into this field, ie 21.4, 19.7, etc.

Ideally, the version would be better suited attached to the CUSTOMER table once the entry was added into the HISTORY table, but that change has not been made.

What I am trying to do with my report is group and display my results as follows:

- Version Number

  - Customer Name

I can get this far, but the issue I am running into is, I only want to show the customer on their latest version number and suppress all previous records so I can get an accurate count of how many and which customers are on each version.  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to create a VIEW in the database, create one that joins Ticket to History, groups on Ticket ID, and returns the Ticket ID and the Max of the Version.

In Crystal, you can then simply joint to that View.

Comment: Unfortunately, I unable to make modifications to the database.

Comment: You can create a Command with the same logic. Performance would be slower though.

Comment: That would be ok as this report does not get run often and when it does, its just once or twice a year when my manager will need it.  I will need to read up on creating commands as I have never done them before.